# Javascript returning empty array (which shoudn't) on IE

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, bookmarks

I've written some code to display my bookmarks on IE8. The code works fine except the array of favorites I should have ("favs") as output exists but is empty (when I put "favs" in the developer tools console I get {...}).

```
var fso, favs = [];
var favString="";
function GetFavourites(Folder) {
    var FavFolder = fso.GetFolder(Folder);
    //Gets Favourite Names & URL's for given folder.
    var files = new Enumerator(FavFolder.Files);
    for (; !files.atEnd(); files.moveNext()) {
        var fil = files.item();
        if (fil.Type == "Internet Shortcut") {
            var textReader = fso.OpenTextFile(fil.Path, 1, false, -2);
            var favtext = textReader.ReadAll();
            var start = favtext.indexOf("URL", 16);
            var stop = favtext.indexOf("\n", start);
            favString = fil.Name.replace(/.url/, "");
            favString += ":URL:";
            //to separate favourite name & favorite URL
            favString += favtext.substring(start + 4, stop - 1);
            favs.push(favString);
        }
    }
    //Checks any subfolder exists
    var subfolders = new Enumerator(FavFolder.SubFolders);
    for (; !subfolders.atEnd(); subfolders.moveNext()) {
        var folder = subfolders.item();
        GetFavourites(folder.Path);
    }
}
function Import() {
    try {
        fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        if (fso !== null) {
            //Create windows script shell object to access Favorites folder in user system.
            var object = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
            var favfolderName = object.SpecialFolders("Favorites");
            if (favString === "") {
                GetFavourites(favfolderName);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert("Security settings to be modified in your browser ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried typing `favs[0]` in your console? As far as i know, IE8's debugging tool cannot display the contents of an array of orbject.

Comment: @freaktm Yes I've tried; I've tried also to go through the array with a For structure. But I'm pretty sure the array is empty because I get 0 with favs.length

Comment: Have you checked your favourites folder (C:\Users\Bruno\Favorites) isn't empty? =)

Comment: @Andy E Yes, I've checked and my favorites are there  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found where my mistake is : I forgot I was using IE in French so the test "if (fil.Type == "Internet Shortcut")" doesn't work; I must replace "Internet Shortcut" with the French equivalent "Raccourci Internet". :-))